# How much glucose oxidase is usually deposited on a glucometer strip?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, enzymes, sensor

The concentration of serum glucose is on average roughly around 5 mmol/L and let's say a typical blood droplet applied to a glucometer is 1μL. We are therefore depositing 5 nmol of glucose on the test strip. 

  These 5 nmol of glucose interact with the enzyme glucose oxidase and through a redox mediator a current is measured. This current is proportional to the concentration of glucose present and it is in the order of few μA (see Figures below taken from Ref.1 and 2). 
Each glucose molecule is oxidased to glucono-lactone by the enzyme glucose oxidase releasing 2 electrons to the amperometric circuit; that means that if we have 5 nmol of glucose, then 10 nmol of electrons are released or equivalently around 1 mC:
$$Equation 1: \frac{10*10^{-9}mol*6.022*10^{23}electron/mol}{6.24*10^{18}  electron/C} ≃ 1 mC $$

Once the oxidation of glucose starts, the current measured increases reaching its maximum for few seconds (time-frame of maximum stability) and then decays. The current used to calibrate and measure the concentration of glucose is taken during this stable time-frame of maximum current.
  If the current measured is of few μA (i.e. let's say 10 μA), that means that in 4 seconds (I have read 2-4 s is typical), only 40 μC (or 0.04 mC) are released and this accounts for 4% of the total number of electrons that would be released if all the glucose contained in the blood droplet is oxidised (see equation 1). 

 **1.Does it mean that usually less than 10% of all glucose is effectively oxidised? if yes, why? What are the main factors that limit the yield so much?**

It is also very difficult to find data on how much glucose oxidase is deposited on the strip. If the max current is roughly around 10 μA that means that 10 μC (or $6.24*10^{13}$electrons or ~ 0.1 nmol of electrons) are released every second; this means that 0.05 nmol of glucose are oxidised every seconds. 

 Glucose oxidase can be considered to follow a Michaelis-Menten law:

$ Equation 2:  v = Kcat*[E_0]\frac{[S]}{Km+S}$, with $[E_0]$ the concentration of the glucose oxidase and $[S]$ of glucose (substrate)

$Kcat$ can be estimated to be around 740 $s^{-1}$, and Km 18 mM (see ref.3); in this example $[S]$ was 5 mmol/L and the enzyme was oxidising at a rate of 0.05 nmol/s. 

 If we consider that the initial volume of the blood droplet (1 μL) is largely preserved during its travel to the reaction area of the strip, then $v = 5*10^{-5}M/s$.

 From this approximate data and equation 2, $[E_0]$ can be estimated to be around 0.3μM; considering the volume of 1 μL, then there are around $3*10^{-13}$ mol of glucose oxidase deposited on the strip or 50 ng (multiplying by the molecular mass of glucose oxidase, 160 kDa).

 **2. Is 50 ng a reasonable estimate? Does anyone know (approximately) how much glucose oxidase is deposited on a strip?**

[image]

1. Volume 2019, Article ID 5948182, The Influence of Blood Glucose Meter Resistance Variation on the Performance of a Biosensor with a Gold-Coated Circuit Board, https://doi.org/10.1155/2019/5948182,
   [image]
2. https://slideplayer.com/slide/5728209/
3. Isolation, purification and characterization of a novel glucose oxidase from Penicillium sp. CBS 120262 optimally active at neutral pH, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.pep.2006.09.013